# mutex with pthread

Tags: linux, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I need to call a function that returns a unique id,

```
int getid()
{
static id=0;
id++;
return id;

}
```

Multiple threads need to call this function, my problem is I'm not sure where I need to lock the mutex,

Do I need to lock before and after calling the function like below

```
  pthread_mutex_lock( &id );
  int id = getid()
  pthread_mutex_unlock( &id );
```

can someone help me with that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really matter where it was locked as long as it was before the access to the shared state.  It would be less prone to errors if the mutex locking was inside the function. Something minimal like this would work:

```
int getid()
{
static int id=0;

pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
int newId = ++id;
pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );

return newId; 
}
```

There are some issues around the initialization of the static variable being thread safe that you may want to look into.

Comment: I've done exactly that, what I was thinking about is the return newId, what I mean is this, when the function get called then reached the return, then it's called again, would that affect the first return ?

Comment: Since newId is not a static variable, it will be located in the stack of the calling thread. Each thread has a separate stack so they will not interfere with each other.

Comment: Thanks, so is it ok to make id a global var and in this case I'll have no issues with the static in a thread isn't safe?

Answer (score 2):

For a single integer you don't need a full mutex, [*atomic increment*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) would be enough:

```
int getid() {
    static int id = 0;
    return __sync_fetch_and_add( &id, 1 );
}
```